# Проверка введенных значений - на бекенде или на фронтенде?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Где лучше проводить проверку введенных значений при регистрации? На бекенде или на фронтенде?

Или там и там?

Comment: да *(8 символов нужно...)*

Comment: На бэкенде однозначно! На фронте можно показать что не все заполнено, но имея небольшие навыки эти проверки можно убрать и тогда на бэк улетит черти что.

Comment: Если без шуток, рекомендуется на обоих концах проверять. А как делать - решать вам. Можете ничего не проверять. Никто вас не заставит)

Comment: точно)тогда но обеих сторонах)Спасибо)Глупый вопрос вышел)